# How to make mouse pointers left-handed friendly in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, mouse

In Windows 7, I could follow [this tutorial on How-To Geek](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/15833/make-your-mouse-pointers-left-hand-friendly). However, it doesn't seem to work for Windows 8.

How do I force the left-handed pointers to fit Windows 8 style now?

Comment: Exactly the same way?  The mouse pointer has not changed in Windows 8.

Comment: Yeap, I realized that the method does not need to be changed, now what I want is a set of win8 style left-handed pointers, they are a little different from aero style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some searching, I think this one: [RealWorld Cursor Editor](http://www.rw-designer.com/cursor-maker) solved my problem, though it costs me some time to produce mirror cursors from those origins in Windows 8. Anyway, thanks for everyone above, for your helping and theaching. :-)

Answer (score 1):

if I understood your problem correctly, you want to switch the functions of the left and right button.
If so - and you may have found out this by now - open the Control Panel -> Mouse > Buttons.
**Check which device is listed**. If you are using a laptop, in Windows 8 chances are that the in-built touchpad will be listed as the default device, even if you're using a mouse. 
Make sure you select "other pointing devices" from the dropdown menu, then select the "left-handed" button.

This was the case with my laptop/Win 8, and the procedure described above worked.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Charms → Search → (settings) "mouse" → Mouse
2. Select "Switch primary and secondary buttons"

The method of getting to the Control Panel is a little different in Windows 8, but once there things are the same for mouse properties.

Comment: You can press `Windows` + `W` to get right to the Settings search.